# How can i build a list of recipients in the email request in Graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to send an email using graph explorer and i need to send to a number of recipients .
How can i construct a list of emails in the body using c# .

So far i have

```
        var emailTo = "test1@acme.com,test2@acme.com";
        var emailList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in emailTo.Split(','))
        {
            emailList.Add(item);
        }
        var emailbody = new
        {
            message = new
            {
                subject = "test details",
                body = new
                {
                    contentType = "Text",
                    content = "The test details content."
                },
                toRecipients = emailList
            }
        };
```

but when i look at the request it isnt constructed correctly as the following Graph api expects.

```
    {
          "message": {
          "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
          "body": {
              "contentType": "Text",
              "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
            },
           "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                   "address": "garthf@contoso.com"
                 }
             }
           ]
        }
     }
```

How can i set an array of recipients ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `list` of `Recipients` and assign it to `ToRecipients`

```
var toRecipients = new List<Recipient>();
var emailTo = "test1@acme.com,test2@acme.com";
foreach (var recipient in emailTo.Split(','))
{
    toRecipients.Add(new Recipient
    {
        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
        {
            Address = recipient
        }
    });
}
var message = new Message
{
    Subject = "Subject",
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = "<div>Text</div>"
    },
    ToRecipients = toRecipients
};
```